# BigQuery job history in UI has disappeared

Tags: google-bigquery, jobs

Experienced a weird problem with BigQuery UI this morning - for a specific project, all Job History both Personal and Project has disappeared. Load jobs are still showing up in the last month when i use the BQ LS command.

Has anyone seen this before, any advice? I've raised a call with the service desk but wondered what you guys think.

best wishes

Dave

Comment: It is a bug in UI. Service desk should be able to find owner to fix it.

Comment: hello also facing bigqquery UI issue :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70015536/bigquery-query-job-history-has-disappeared-from-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the BigQuery UI, there is a public issue reporting this scenario [1], as a workaround you can list all the jobs by using the CLI [2]

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/118569383

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#listing_jobs_in_a_project

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a shared, 1000 query / job list maximum in the UI. As we had begun to run many hundreds of queries per day, this was 'pushing' the job queries out of the list. I've requested this to be increased as a feature request in future

best wishes

Dave